# How to edit name of the existing Group name using XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, node-xmpp

Currently i am making chat application and i required to Edit group name.

if any one have solution then please send me because i spend many hours for edit group name but not found any solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please clarify if you are trying to rename Groupchat or Roster group. More, please add your code.

Comment: Hello Mr.Pk,
i will rename Group(Room)name .I have not found any code for rename Room name. if you have any code then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [iOS XMPPFramework - Room / chat messages history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395335/ios-xmppframework-room-chat-messages-history) hints (@Moral 's answer) about Persistant room, you have to keep in mind that

1) Groupchat name, as JID (JabberID) it's unique ID and cannot be changed in any way. So you'll cannot change `mychatroom1@conference.myserver`

2) Groupchat topic (and/or description) can be changed. I can't find a decent tutorial about, however, looking at previous answer, you'll have to add something like that (look point 3):

```
-(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm {
    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields) {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
        // Change room name
if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_roomname"]) {
           [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
           [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"myNewName"]];
       }
       }
    }
    [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
}
```

Pay attention: if an user has not the grants to change the room name, you must enable the change name permissions. Again, while sending the form, you have to send before something like

```
-(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm {
    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields) {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
        // Make Room Persistent
       if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_changesubject"]) {
           [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
           [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"true"]];
// if does not works:         [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" booleanValue:@"true"]];

 }
        }
        [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
    }
```

Look at official spec to understand how [Multiuserchat (groupchat)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) works

More, this answer about how to configure a MUC may help you [XMPPFramework - Implement Group Chat (MUC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268629/xmppframework-implement-group-chat-muc)

Comment: Thank you for helping me.i will try it.

Comment: Now i changed subject of group successfully but not get new subject if any code then please help me.

Comment: I have no idea, start to search for "xmppframework groupchat delegate", maybe helps!

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer and i spent lots of hour for get subject of the room but not found any solution.so if you will find any solution then please help me.

Comment: Can member of the muc group change the name of room or edit muc group image?